# How do I get WebStorm to treat Vue template shorthands as correct when using lang="pug"?

Tags: vue.js, pug, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image: This code is correct but WebStorm highlights the shorthand ":"as an unexpected token]

In the above template in a .vue file the shorthand for `v-bind:class`, `:class` is highlighted as incorrect even though it is correct and actually works when the template is compiled. This also happens with the v-on shorthand `@`. It only happens when `lang="pug"`, and does not effect the compilation of the template.

I assume that this is because WebStorm is using the pug compiler to generate errors, without taking into account the fact that this pug code is in a Vue template. But I am unsure of how to fix it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** `@click` is not flagged as incorrect here, but any subsequent `@foo` put into the attributes becomes flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, please follow [WEB-28010](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28010) for updates